# What's the difference between @ and $ when accessing Ant properties?

Tags: ant

What's the difference between `@{property}` and `${property}` in accessing Ant properties?

Didn't see any obvious note about it in the Ant manual.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`${property}` is the normal way to access properties. `@{property}` is used inside macro definitions to access arguments passed to this macro. See the [Ant manual on macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

Answer (score 10):

`${property}` is used to reference [Properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#properties).

`@{attribute}` is used to reference [Attributes in `<macrodef>` Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).